# How can I skip a specific Index in an array in a for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I had a function that is pulling in values from somewhere and storing those values into an array.

```
function getSport(ply) {
   some code here... //function gets values that I need for array later
}

var sports1 = getSport(playerChoice); 
var sports2 = getSport(playerChoice);
var sports3 = getSport(playerChoice);
var sports4 = getSport(playerChoice);

var sportsArry = [sports1, sports2, sports3, sports4];
```

Now I would like to use a for loop to loop the elements, the problem, however, is the first index (index 0) will always be true.  I want to skip index 0.  How do I do that?  Further I want to replace index 0 with something else.  Let me show you

```
for (var i = 0; i<sportsArry.length; i++){
  if ( (sports1 == sportsArry[i])  ) {
     sports1 = null;   //I figured I should null it first?
     sports1 = replaceValueFunc(playerChoice2);
  }
}
```

Well you can see the problem I would have.  Index 0 is true.

Let me show you what would work, although it requires alot of or operators.

```
if ( (sports1 == sportsArry[1]) || (sports1 == sportsArry[2]) || (sports1 == sportsArry[3] ) {
```

...
}

^^ That is one way to skip index 0, what would be another better looking way?

Comment: Can't you just start your loop at 1 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to skip index 0. How do I do that? Further I want to replace
>   index 0 with something else.

Just start the loop from `1` instead of `0`

```
sportsArr[0] = "Something else"; // set the first element to something else
for(var i = 1; i < sportsArr.length; i++){ 
   // do something
}
```